# CSS Styling for two adjacent div

Tags: html, css

I have a section element .In that I have created two adjacent elements article and aside (inline-block) . The article has two child div(block). The resultant display can be seen in the code snippet . In the resultant display the content becomes of unequal heights . There becomes a gap at the top when the content is of unequal height . How to fix it semantically ?

```css
article,aside{
display:inline-block;
  width:40%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#div-1,#div-2{

display:block;
}
```

```html
<section>
<article>
      <div id='div-1'>Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum<br>Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum<br>Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum<br>Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum<br>Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum<br></div>
      <div id='div-2'>Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum<br>Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum<br>Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum<br>Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum<br>Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum<br>Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum<br></div>
  
</article>
  <aside>dummy texstdummy texstdummy texstdummy texst<br>dummy texstdummy texstdummy texstdummy texst<br>dummy texstdummy texstdummy texstdummy texst<br>dummy texstdummy texstdummy texstdummy texst<br>dummy texstdummy texstdummy texstdummy texst<br>dummy texstdummy texstdummy texstdummy texst<br>dummy texstdummy texstdummy texstdummy texst<br>dummy texstdummy texstdummy texstdummy texst<br></aside>
</section>
```

Comment: Use `vertical-align` on inline-blocks

Comment: Inline-block are default to align to baseline of the parent element which is why you are seeing this behaviour. So aligning it to the top vertically will solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `float` instead of `display: block;`?

```
article, aside {float: left;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fy9yjazt/1/

Comment: Both the solutions are working perfectly . But which is more semantic ?  @young shot

Comment: @Abhishek: CSS can't be semantic, just HTML can be. CSS set just a style, design. `Float` solution is shorter (1 definiton instead of two - display&vertical-align). No other differents aren't there in this case. Just one: `inline-block` elements make you a gap between them, `float` none.

Comment: @Abhishek if there is a particular reason for you to use inline block then you should apply the vertical align. Float behaves different than inline block, just double check your layout after

Comment: @Huangism in the context of my problem, float is fitting well .

Answer (score 4):

You must set a vertical-align like this :

```
article, aside {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```